# One line of pixels while copying BMP keeps getting lost

Tags: c, image, dynamic-memory-allocation, bmp

I am trying to copy a bmp file (bmp version windows v5) using an array and a structure to store the image data. And it works, kinda, but the top line of pixels in the output file keeps getting lost somewhere. In hex editor I see that some info just isn`t copied for some reason.

I tried using different versions of .bmp, v3 and v5 to be exact. It seems that the problem is that I process BMP V5 data incorrectly somehow(not enough memory? but only for the top line of px exactly?), as V3 images are copied intact.

Here're structures:

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)
typedef struct {
    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t reserved1;
    uint16_t reserved2;
    uint32_t offset;
    uint32_t dib_header_size;
    int32_t  width_px;
    int32_t  height_px;
    uint16_t num_planes;
    uint16_t bits_per_pixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t image_size_bytes;
    int32_t  x_resolution_ppm;
    int32_t  y_resolution_ppm;
    uint32_t num_colors;
    uint32_t important_colors;
} BMPHeader;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t reserved;
} Pixel;
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef struct {
    BMPHeader *header;
    Pixel **pixel;
} BMPImage;
```

The function to read image info:

```
BMPImage* read_image (FILE *file) {
    BMPHeader *header = malloc(sizeof(BMPHeader));
    BMPImage *image = malloc(sizeof(BMPImage));

    if (header == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR - Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fread(header, sizeof(BMPHeader), 1, file) < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR - Cannot read the header\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    image->header = header;
    image->pixel = malloc(header->width_px * sizeof(Pixel *));
    for (int i = 0; i < header->width_px; i++) {
        image->pixel[i] = malloc(header->height_px * sizeof(Pixel));
    }

    uint8_t zero = 0;
    unsigned int padding = get_padding(header);
    for (int i = header->height_px - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < header->width_px; j++) {
            fread(&(image->pixel[j][i]), sizeof(Pixel), 1, file);
        }
        fread(&(zero), sizeof(uint8_t), padding, file);
    }
    return image;
}
```

The function to write the info into new file:

```
void write_image (BMPHeader *header, Pixel **pixel) {
    FILE *ff = open_file("./out.bmp", "wb");
    fwrite(header, sizeof(BMPHeader), 1, ff);

    uint8_t zero = 0;
    unsigned int padding = get_padding(header);
    for (int i = header->height_px - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < header->width_px; j++) {
            fwrite(&pixel[j][i], sizeof(Pixel), 1, ff);
        }
        fwrite(&(zero), sizeof(uint8_t), padding, ff);
    }
    fclose(ff);
}
```

And the padding function just to be sure I got it right:

```
int get_padding (BMPHeader *header) {
    return (4 - (header->width_px * header->bits_per_pixel) % 4) % 4;
}
```

I am mostly studying how to work with bitmaps, so I'm sorry if the problem is trivial or solution is obvious. I`m stuck. I understand that there must be other and easier ways to do it, but I need to do it using an array and without any fancy libraries.

Comment: What happens with `fread(&(zero), sizeof(uint8_t), padding, file)` if `padding > 1`? Same thing when you write, what will be written if `padding > 1`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I dont really understand how to work with padding, to be honest. I intended for it to be read into zero at the end of each line and be written into new file the same way. I mean, if I haven`t mistaken formula for padding, fread and fwrite will do something only if the width % 4 > 0, but lost pixel line is still here with padding = 0

Comment: You have a single `uint8_t` variable named `zero`, but if `padding` is larger than `1` then you will attempt to read `padding` number of `uint8_t` into the single variable. You need an *array* to be able to handle all the possible paddings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wait, in classes we were told that padding basically is junk bits of info used to make calculations for pc easier. So I should just skip it when reading info into pixel array and add 0 when I write data into file.
I mean, this missing line problem exists solely in v5 versions but in v3 bmps with padding > 1 i dont have this issue.
Maybe you`re right, but wouldnt then this missing pixel line exist in all bmps with padding > 1 regardless of version? Sorry, Im genuinely trying to understand

Comment: If you read more than one byte into the single byte variable `zero`, you basically go out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*. And if you have undefined behavior then your whole program is ill-formed. If you want to skip padding perhaps it would be better to [*seek*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) over the parts you don't need.

Comment: You also have no checks for the file [its format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) and its headers. For example you don't take into account if the height is *negative* (which it can be).

Comment: Lastly I also recommend you use a small image known to follow the format you're reading, and then use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement to see what really happens in the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude alright, thank you! I`ll try to use fseek, it does sound better suited for what I need.

Comment: You can use `fseek` when writing to the file as well.